# How can I parse this JSON to a C# object?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON stream that I would like to parse as a C# object. This stream is not something I can change, so I have to deal with it, but it doesn't seem right?

Anyway who knows how to parse this with help of e.g. JSON.NET?

```
[
{
    "items": {
        "4": {
            "IdNummer": "4",
            "Title": "Bewaak je hart deel 3",
            "Server": "cdn11.streampartner.nl",
            "PublishPoint": "plompd",
            "Filename": "Bewaak je hart deel 3.mp3",
            "activated": "1",
            "Date": "Dec 21:12",
            "Filesize": "28950111",
            "Thumbnail": "",
            "Comments": "",
            "UserToken": "plom04a18847262fe15",
            "ItemTokenNumber": "0661ce1e4fe256d1",
            "Category": "",
            "StartDate": "0000-00-00",
            "EndDate": "0000-00-00"
        },
        "5": {
            "IdNummer": "5",
            "Title": "Bewaak je hart deel 2",
            "Server": "cdn11.streampartner.nl",
            "PublishPoint": "plompd",
            "Filename": "Bewaak je hart deel 2.mp3",
            "activated": "1",
            "Date": "Dec 22:37",
            "Filesize": "41461227",
            "Thumbnail": "",
            "Comments": "",
            "UserToken": "plom04a18847262fe15",
            "ItemTokenNumber": "6b8eddbf612653e9",
            "Category": "",
            "StartDate": "0000-00-00",
            "EndDate": "0000-00-00"
        }
    }
}
```

]

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: @CodeMonkey It's too complicated for that I'm afraid, but it does provide DTOs for the base items :(

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yeah I tried JSON.NET in combination with json2csharp, but like JohnD said, this is not valid JSON (for json2csharp). So I'll see if I can trick it like L.B. suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Since your json contains numeric property names like `"1"` which can not be used as variable name in c#, you can use the `Dictionary<string,SomeObject>` trick. So  using Json.Net,

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ItemContainer>>(json);
```

---

```
public class ItemContainer
{
    public Dictionary<string,Item> Items { get; set; }
}
public class Item
{
    public string IdNummer { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Server { get; set; }
    public string PublishPoint { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string activated { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Filesize { get; set; }
    public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public string UserToken { get; set; }
    public string ItemTokenNumber { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Same thing I just said.  Just different library.

Comment: "I use NewtonSoft.Json.dll. Works great." Not even close.

Comment: @Casey I used the same library  (`Json.Net = NewtonSoft.Json.dll`)  :)  But saying only *"something works great"* is not an answer.

Comment: @Casey `Same thing I just said. Just different library` **LOL :)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm gonna try the trick-json.net-approach!